# minimizing the jframe window with a jbutton click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jdialog

I know to minimize the jframe, I need to use setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
But what I am trying to figure out is how to get to the frame.  This dialog is child of a parent dialog.  Here is the Constructor.

```
    public EdiBaseDialog(EdiDialogHandler edh, Frame parent, TCSession theSession) {
      super(parent, false);
      session = theSession;
      createDialog();
   }
```

So when I try to add `setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED)` command in my jbutton actionPerformed.  Which is in a JPanel Method.

I do not know how to address the frame.

```
??.setState(JFrame.ICONFIED);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`Dialog.getOwner()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getOwner%28%29) from within the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go up in the component hierarchy until you arrive at the Frame. There are already helper methods in Swing to do this. Try SwingUtilties:

> SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, this);

(Where 'this' can be any component in the hierarchy)
Of course this will only be of use if your dialogs are forming a proper hierarchy (no dialogs using a NULL owner. If thats the case, you have to pass in the Frame through some method or constructor.